# What does mean long stream of bytes preceded by a handshake message in Bittorrent?

Tags: bittorrent

I'm developing implement Bittorrent without using any library. I have tried to send a handshake message to a peer. I think this handshake would be symmetric by both side. But the peers sends a little weird handshake to me. For example, when I send the following handshake message to a peer,

```
\x13BitTorrent protocol\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0<sha1 info hash><20byte of my peer-id>
```

I expect the handshake message like

```
\x13BitTorrent protocol\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0<sha1 info hash><20byte of peer-id>
```

But I get

```
\x13BitTorrent protocol\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0<sha1 info hash><20byte of peer-id><long stream of many bytes>
```

What does the long stream mean? any specs have never explained this.
Also, whenever I receive a handshake message, that stream size is always different.

Answer (score 1):

If you are the initiator and has already sent your handshake message, the other peer answer with a handshake and can then immediately start to send normal bittorrent messages. That is the long stream you see.